# Unable to select value from dropdown for day,month and year dropdown option in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

[image]

I am not able to select value from drop down for day, month and year while doing the registration on boohoo ecommerce site due to which I am not able to do further actions.

```
could you please help me to resolve this issue

site:http://www.boohoo.com/

steps1 :open URL of Boohoo, 

Step 2: Go to User Icon then click on registeration link

==============================================
public class Boohoo {
      WebDriver driver;

      @BeforeMethod
      public void beforeMethod() {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
      ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

      Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
      prefs.put("password_manager_enabled", false); 
      options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
      options.addArguments("start-maximized");
      options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
      driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

 }  
      @Test(priority=3)
  public void BoohooURLverify() {
     driver.get("http://www.boohoo.com/");
     String Title=driver.getTitle();
     if(Title.endsWith("http://www.boohoo.com/"))
     {
         System.out.println("Url is verifedand is correct");
     }
     else

     System.out.println("Incorrect URl is opened");
     driver.quit();

  }
      @Test(priority=1)
      public void BohooRegisteration() {
         driver.get("http://www.boohoo.com/");
         Actions Action=new Actions(driver);
         WebElement User_link=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div[4]/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/div/span"));
        WebElement Register_link=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div[4]/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/div/div/div/a[2]"));
        Action.moveToElement(User_link).moveToElement(Register_link).click().build().perform();
        WebElement Register_page_title=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main']/div/h1")) ;
         String Register_page_Title=Register_page_title.getText();
         System.out.println(Register_page_Title);
         if (Register_page_Title=="Create Account")
         {
             System.out.println("Page Title is correct");
         }
         else
         {
             System.out.println("Incorrect title of registration page");
         }
         Select drpdwn1=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dwfrm_profile_customer_title']")));
         drpdwn1.selectByVisibleText("Miss");
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dwfrm_profile_customer_firstname']")).sendKeys("Rashmi");
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dwfrm_profile_customer_lastname']")).sendKeys("Patil");
         Select drpdwn2=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dwfrm_profile_customer_dayofbirth']")));

        drpdwn1.selectByVisibleText("05");
         drpdwn1.selectByIndex(02);
         Select drpdwn3=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dwfrm_profile_customer_monthofbirth']")));
         drpdwn1.selectByVisibleText("05");
         Select drpdwn4=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dwfrm_profile_customer_yearofbirth']")));
         drpdwn1.selectByVisibleText("1990");
         Select drpdwn5=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dwfrm_profile_customer_gender']")));
         drpdwn1.selectByVisibleText("Female");
         driver.findElement(By.id("dwfrm_profile_customer_email")).sendKeys("vaishali.1990@rediffmail.com");
         driver.findElement(By.id("dwfrm_profile_customer_emailconfirm")).sendKeys("vaishali.1990@rediffmail.com");
         driver.findElement(By.id("dwfrm_profile_login_password_d0dazcxwlbzi")).sendKeys("vaishali.1990@rediffmail.com");
         driver.findElement(By.id("dwfrm_profile_login_passwordconfirm_d0ehbfaagjuv")).sendKeys("vaishali.1990@rediffmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='RegistrationForm']/fieldset[2]/div[9]/button")).click();
        System.out.println("Account should be created sucessfully");
         driver.close();
      }
}
```

==============================================
Error message: Below it's the error

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate element with text: 05
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
System info: host: 'D90ZC6Q1', ip: '192.168.163.235', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.selectByVisibleText(Select.java:150)
    at ecommerce_pack1.Boohoo.BohooRegisteration(Boohoo.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@1b40d5f0: 243 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@35851384: 56 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@1ae369b7: 46 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 65 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@d7b1517: 8 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@2b80d80f: 111 ms
```

Comment: Is it's a drop down with select tag?

Comment: Yes, tags are given to drpdwn as Days,months

Comment: it is with select tag as follow>>                                                              <div class="form-birthday-rows-inner">
<div class="form-row dayofbirth js-birthday js-day form-row-one-third">
<label for="dwfrm_profile_customer_dayofbirth">
<div class="field-wrapper select-wrapper">
<select id="dwfrm_profile_customer_dayofbirth" class="input-select dayofbirth" name="dwfrm_profile_customer_dayofbirth">
</div>
<div class="form-caption"/>

Comment: is selectByValue(5) or selectbyindex working?

Comment: not working, it is giving an error no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Once you open the url `https://www.boohoo.com` and browse to the `https://www.boohoo.com/register` page, the following code block will select `Day` as `05`, `Month` as `05` and `Year` as `1990`:

```
    WebElement day_dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("dwfrm_profile_customer_dayofbirth"));
    Select day = new Select(day_dropdown);
    day.selectByVisibleText("05");
    WebElement month_dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("dwfrm_profile_customer_monthofbirth"));
    Select month = new Select(month_dropdown);
    month.selectByVisibleText("05");
    WebElement year_dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("dwfrm_profile_customer_yearofbirth"));
    Select year = new Select(year_dropdown);
    year.selectByVisibleText("1990");
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

You have made few mistakes in your program. You have used the incorrect dropdown for sending values.

**Lines of your code**

```
     Select drpdwn2=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dwfrm_profile_customer_dayofbirth']")));
     drpdwn1.selectByVisibleText("05");
     drpdwn1.selectByIndex(02);
```

**Modified Code**

```
     Select drpdwn2=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dwfrm_profile_customer_dayofbirth']")));
     drpdwn2.selectByVisibleText("05");
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the select approaches work, you can click the dropdown arrow to open it and then click By.linkText("05"). Is not as elegant solution as the other ones, but should do the work.